# Failed prop type: The prop `children` is marked as required in `e`, but its value is `null`

Tags: reactjs

In my React app, I'm getting the following error but it doesn't tell me where it's happening. Any idea how I can pinpoint its location? The only place I have `this.props.children` doesn't seem to make any sense for this error.

[image]

UPDATE: 
Here's the `Timeline` component.

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import PerfectScrollBar from 'react-perfect-scrollbar';

// Components
import TimelineEntry from './timelineEntry';

// Defaults
import { AvatarUrl } from '../../../../enum/defaults';

const Timeline = ({ member, conversationId, messages, activeMessageId, handleClickMessageSelected }) => {

    return (
        <div className=" height-100 padding-top-70">

            <div className="padding-15" style={{ position: 'absolute', top: '0', left: '0' }}>

                {typeof conversationId !== "undefined" && conversationId !== ""
                    ? <div className="timeline-item-msg" id="msc-newConversationMessage">

                        <img src={member.avatar ? member.avatar.smallAvatarUrl : AvatarUrl.avatar} className="tim-image" />
                        <div className="tim-msg">
                            <div className="tim-msg-body cursor-pointer border-radius">
                                New Message
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    : null
                }
            </div>

            <div className="height-100 position-relative padding-15">

                <PerfectScrollBar>
                    {
                        messages.length > 0
                            ? messages.map(item => <TimelineEntry key={item.id} entry={item} activeMessageId={activeMessageId} handleClickMessageSelected={handleClickMessageSelected} />)
                            : null
                    }
                </PerfectScrollBar>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

Timeline.PropTypes = {

    member: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    conversationId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    messages: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    activeMessageId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleClickMessageSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Timeline;
```

And this is the `TimelineEntry` component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

// Defaults
import { AvatarUrl } from '../../../../enum/defaults';

// Utils
import { shortenTextToMaxCharacters } from '../../../../utils/string/stringUtils';

const TimelineEntry = ({ entry, activeMessageId, handleClickMessageSelected }) => {

    let wrapperClass = 'timeline-item-msg';
    if (entry.userFlag != 0)
        wrapperClass += ' flag-' + entry.userFlag;

    if (entry.id === activeMessageId)
        wrapperClass += ' active';

    return (
        <div className={wrapperClass} id={'mst-' + entry.id} onClick={e => handleClickMessageSelected(entry.id)}>

            <img src={entry.sender.avatarUrl ? entry.sender.avatarUrl : AvatarUrl.avatar} className="tim-image" />

            <div className="tim-msg">

                <div className="tim-msg-header">

                    {entry.sender.fullName} <br /><span className="opacity-6">{entry.messageTimeStamp.weekDay}  {entry.messageTimeStamp.date} <i className="margin-right-40">{entry.messageTimeStamp.time}</i></span>

                </div>

                <div className="tim-msg-body cursor-pointer">

                    {shortenTextToMaxCharacters(entry.body.trim(), 75)}

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    );
}

TimelineEntry.PropTypes = {

    entry: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    activeMessageId: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    handleClickMessageSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default TimelineEntry;
```

Comment: You must be using some library which expects that you pass a child component to it. Example `<LibraryComponent> <MyComponent /> </LibraryComponent>`

Comment: This just started happening and I didn't add anything new. I'm working on the app so there are code changes but no new libs. Is there a way for me to pinpoint the location of the error? And why does it show up as a warning but act like an error?

Comment: This is not an error. It's a `propType` warning. Like you write in your component using `propTypes` that this particular component will receive the xyz props. Now wherever this warning is coming from, there must be some prop assertions and there it asserts that children prop is required.

Comment: Can you please post your TimeLine component?

Comment: Just posted the `Timeline` component in the UPDATE section of original post.

Comment: Can you please post the TimelineEntry component as well?

Comment: Just posted the `TimelineEntry` component code. Thanks for helping me with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `PerfectScrollBar` component that you are using in your `Timeline` component has a propType `children: PropTypes.node.isRequired`. (Code at https://github.com/goldenyz/react-perfect-scrollbar/blob/master/src/scrollbar.js)

In the `Timeline` component, when `messages.length` is 0, you are rendering `null`; which is causing no `children` to render for `PerfectScrollBar`, which in turn is giving the propType warning.

The workaround for this would be to render an empty div, `<div></div>` instead of `null` so that the propTypes of the `PerfectScrollBar` are satisfied.

Comment: #SOReadyToHelp Always a pleasure!  :)